# Delete existing code in salesforce before putting a new build

Tags: ant, salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

Is there a way to delete all the existing files in salesforce sandbox before putting a new deployment there. I have tried by creating `destructiveChanges.xml` there. But I couldnt run deploy task in ANT since it was exiting giving an error. Same error giving when I run the undeployCode task also. So I had to remove the `destructiveChanges.xml`. Otherwise I could not put a deploy.

This is the ANT error.

`Failed to process the request successfully. Cause(UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION): UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION: An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 866321560-256048 (-980318090)`

Soon after I remove the `destructiveChanges.xml` it was running fine again.

So I was able to put a deploy. But still could not figure out a way to undeploy the stuffs.

Can someone help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to run a "full clean" of your sandbox before deployment. In my experience, this is harder than it sounds; destructiveChanges.xml does work but I've run into weird inter-dependency issues when trying to do mass deletes. I came to the conclusion that it's much easier to simply provision a brand new sandbox when you want to do a "clean all" equivalent. YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

From the [force.com developer boards](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Apex-Code-Development/Delete-Apex-class-from-production/m-p/211645#M37620) (I have used this technique successfully):

> 1. From Force.com IDE, select the class that you want to delete (Look for .xml extension )
> 2. Open that .xml version of your class and change the Status tag to Deleted.
> 3. Right click and save the file.
> 4. Now select "SRC" folder and right click--->Select  Force.com---> select Deploy to server
> 5. Log into your production org and follow the steps.

I'm not aware of any other way to delete code from production.

Comment: You can also directly delete class from Force.com IDE project attached to production server. It will kickoff a full test run of other classes and will fail if dependencies are violated but it works for quick'n'dirty removal.

Comment: Edited the meta data file for a class,and deployed. But the file is still there in salesforce sandbox. :(

I have edited the meta data file as below.
<code>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ApexClass xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>23.0</apiVersion>
    <status>Deleted</status>
</ApexClass>
</code>

Comment: Deleting the file in production would not automatically remove the file from your sandbox. You need to either perform the same steps in Sandbox or simply go to Setup > Develop > Apex Classes and delete the file there.

Comment: I have noticed that if I change a field in an object  in my IDE, the changed field will get added as a new one in the sandbox, but the old field is still there, Seems its not putting a fresh builds, How can I a put a fresh build everytime.